# why crontab process run repeated auto at sometimes

Tags: linux, cron

sometimes, we found our server's cron process auto repeated, repeated 2 or 3 times

when use ps command, I get this:

```
server_xx14:~ # ps aux | grep cron

root      2596  0.0  0.0  11188   392 ?        Ss    2009   0:25 /usr/sbin/cron
root     21706  0.0  0.0  20812   944 ?        S    09:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
root     23437  0.0  0.0  20812   944 ?        S    09:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
```

I only want just one cron to running, how can i fix this problem? thx!

Answer (score 2):

If you have some long-running and/or failing (never finishing) scripts in cron, they will cause multiple cron processes appearing in the process list.

To see what's going on, try `pstree -ap` and see the cron stuff in a nicely formatted manner, like the one below:

```
  ├─cron─┬─13*[cron───sh───longrunningscript_───php]
  │      └─cron───sh───longrunningscript_───php
```

That would mean cron had started a new shell script, which starts PHP, which takes a long time to run. If pstree is not installed in your system, `ps -auxwwwf` creates a similar view.

If cron behaved any differently, a single long-running cron job might stall all the other scripts meant to run in cron indefinitely. And THAT'S something you don't want.

Comment: what I should do when there is some long-running and/or failing (never finishing) scripts in cron,is there any suggestion?

Comment: Run them by hand and see why they are taking so long.

Comment: some crons need to read and  calculate a lot of datas from database. is there possible to enforce only one cron to run, no matter how long the scripts will running?

Comment: Enforcing has to be done on per-script basis. One popular way is to modify the script to use a lockfile in the beginning of the script and get it deleted at the end of the script. If another cron tries to start the same script, it won't because of the lockfile. There are many ways to do that, dotlockfile utility bundled at least with Ubuntu 10.04 is a very nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running? You should definitely only have 1 instance of cron running. Try running:

```
# /etc/init.d/crond stop
# /etc/init.d/crond start
```

Or which ever `init.d` script your OS uses to kick off cron. If that doesn't work, you can probably run the `stop` command, then `kill` the remaining cron processes, then running the `start`.